# how to have different outcomes from a user input (next question taking the first question user input into account to do calculations)

Tags: python

```
#Elecricity Plan
#these are the electricity plans

eplan = input('Enter your electricity plan (EFIR or EFLR): ')

if eplan.lower() == 'efir':
 print('Thank you for choosing EFIR' )

elif eplan.lower() == 'eflr':
 print('Thank you for choosing EFLR')

else:
 print('Please enter your electricity plan in abbreviation')
```

## Amount of Electricity used

i am trying to make it so that when the person enters their answer to the electricity
plan it does a different calculation in the next question based on if they chose EFIR or EFLR
(responds to their
input after taking into account the amount of electricity used and what plan they had in the
last question)

```
 kwha = int(input('Enter the amount of electricity you used in month '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do two types of calculations based on the first input because you already stored it in the eplan variable:

```
kwha = int(input('Enter the amount of electricity you used in month ')) 
if eplan.lower() == 'efir':
   #do calculation
elif eplan.lower() == 'eflr':
   #do another calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different functions for different user inputs. But its not necessary, you can just use if blocks like you have done!

```
def func_one():
    print('Thank you for choosing EFIR')
    # ...

def func_two():
    print('Thank you for choosing EFLR')
    # ...
```

and then do something like this:

```
if eplan.lower() == 'efir':
    func_one()
elif eplan.lower() == 'eflr':
    func_two()
else:
    print('Please enter your electricity plan in abbreviation')
```

**TIP**:
You can create a hash map for situations like this

```
map = {'efir': func_one, 'eflr': func_two}

if eplan.lower() in map:
    map[eplan.lower()]()
else:
    print('Please enter your electricity plan in abbreviation')
```

You can also use **match**!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using match/case like this by swapping the input order - i.e., ask for the usage amount first then the plan type:

```
amount = float(input('Enter the amount of electricity used: '))

match input('Enter your electricity plan (EFIR or EFLR): '):
    case 'EFIR':
        pass # do EFIR calculations here
    case 'EFLR':
        pass # do EFLR calculations here
    case _:
        print('Unknown plan type')
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple. You can put the code directly inside the conditional blocks or separate it into functions

```
if some_condition_is_true:
    # do calculation or call another function
elif ...
else ...
```